# Best Place for Temp Files in SPO Add-In

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

My project needs to create a text file for the user to download to a place of their choosing.

Wither should I save the temp file?  There must be a place where the app has write permissions and the user has read permissions.  The file only needs to remain long enough for the user's browser session.

([I tried to figure out how to do this with a filestream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399807/how-to-start-save-as-dialog-with-a-filestream) so I wouldn't need a temp location, but it doesn't seem possible.)

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish, or storing?

Comment: You can download file stream without writing to a temporary location.

Comment: see this example. I haven`t try but you can create sample http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Comment: @Mike I just want them to be able to pull a text file to their downloads folder.

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti say, that's a right nice javascript solution; I'm going to check it out - it doesn't answer my question, but it does solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

> > > The file only needs to remain long enough for the user's browser session.

Then use the Browsers `SessionStorage`

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

IE was the last Browser to implement this W3C standard.... in IE 8

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this.  I need to save a file to a temporary location, not just a value.  The reason is so that I can tell the browser to download the file.  I need a temporary location.

Comment: https://eligrey.com/blog/saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side/

Comment: Danny - thanks for the link; I'll consider a javascript solution - although it isn't the answer to my question.